# how to run SQL script in js in orcale apex

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

i want to run sql script inside  Execute when Page Loads in orcale apex

example to explain what i want

```
var result = "SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE condition;";

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You want to execute SQL code... on client-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a Page Load dynamic action (DA).

One option to do what you asked for is to set two steps for that DA. Here's how:

- the first step is to create action whose type is "Execute server-side code". As it is PL/SQL, its `SELECT` requires an `INTO` clause. Into what? A hidden page item (I named it `P2_RESULT`).

  Also, you should pay attention to possible `NO_DATA_FOUND` or `TOO_MANY_ROWS` errors, but - let's presume that query really returns one and one only row. I'm just counting employees:

  ```
  select count(*) into :P2_RESULT from emp;
  ```

  Set "Items to return" property to `P2_RESULT`.
- the second step is "Execute JavaScript code":

  ```
  console.log($v("P2_RESULT"));
  ```

Run the page; when executed, it results in

[image]

(i.e. there are 13 employees in that table).